google login implementation not working in codeIgnite 4 framework
Here, I have implemented in a function name googlelogin:
not getting code back from the OAuth 2.0 flow
`public function googlelogin()
{
    require_once APPPATH . 'Glibraries/vendor/autoload.php';
    // Create a new Google client
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId('your-client-id'); // Replace with your client ID
    $client->setClientSecret('your-client-secret'); // Replace with your client secret
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost:8080/cba/dashboard');
    $client->addScope('email');
    $client->addScope('profile');

    // If code back from the OAuth 2.0 flow
   [ if (isset($_GET['code'])) {](https://stackoverflow.com)
        $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
        // ...
    }
   else 
   {
        // Generate the authentication URL
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        // Redirect the user to the authentication URL
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }
}`

gif file
It doesn't returning code back from OAuth flow, alway redirecting to login page.
I try to debug it , but not going iside this code block. alway going to else condition.
I match redirection url from developer console it is exactly same.
